# Python psutil memory does not match linux command

Tags: python, psutil

I want to know why psutil's virtual memory used or active do not match the value I get from the linux command 'free -m'
What I want to know is the physical system memory used.

```
virtual_memory().total / 1024 / 1024 = 29741
virtual_memory().used / 1024 / 1024 = 7967
virtual_memory().active / 1024 / 1024 = 2259

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          29741        1148       21773          16        6819       28322
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I'm guessing that virtual_memory().used returns physical mem + shared mem + cached mem
but still, active memory should match 1148.

Comment: You are correct, that `virtual_memory().used` includes buffers and cache. There are actually articles on the net on how to correctly interpret the output of the `free` command regarding that topic in general. To get the actually used RAM (without buffers etc.), use `psutil.virtual_memory().total - psutil.virtual_memory().available`.

Comment: I ran it again on other machines. The used memory matched the one from linux command. There might have been an os related bug.

Comment: I've just had a look at the documentation of psutil, and it's stated there, that `.active` is indeed OS dependent (UNIX). See https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#memory